# при запуске пишет: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." input было null

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < input.Length; x++)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы в `GUI` приложении пытаетесь читать консольный ввод?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, nullReferenceException и будет
Смотрите:
В строке `input = Console.Readline()` вы пытаетесь что-то прочитать.
Насколько я понимаю, читать нечего и `input = null`. `null` - потому что это значение по умолчанию для типа `string`.
В цикле (вот здесь `x<input.Length`) вы пытаетесь обратиться к свойству `Length` объекта  `input`. Но у объекта  `input` нет никаких свойств, он же `null`. О чем вам и кричит обработчик. 
Обратиться к самому `input` вы можете. Получите значение `null` и все, но вот попытка обратиться к его внутренним свойствам, которых нет, даст исключение.
Как говорил удав в мультике: "У меня не ни рук, ни ног!!!!"
Как исправить? Сделать проверку на null перед циклом. 
В примитивном варианте: `if(input !=null){}` -> входим в цикл. Иначе - нет.
в более качественном варианте лучше использовать стандартный метод `IsNullOrEmpty()`. Тогда условие будет выглядеть так:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input){for...}
```